# CSV file data manipulation

Tags: powershell, csv, data-manipulation

I have many rows containing 'input' as substring under column 'Column1' but not in contiguous form. For each occurrence of this type, i want to put value 'some data' in another column of same row.
This is what it should be like.

```
Column1                        Column2
This function takes input.     
Other value                    don't care
String as input                old_data

Column1                        Column2

This function takes input.     new_data
Other value                    don't care
String as input                old_data, new_data
```

If the column is empty it should simply add the data but if it already contains some old_data, it should append new_data delimited by comma.
Is there any way to automate this task using powershell or otherwise.

**EDIT**
With your help I have modified the code and it looks something like this.
If value of column3 contains 'input' I have checked in Column 5 if there is already any data(either word character or ',') or not. But there is some problem in if statement.

```
$path = "d:\Book.csv"
$data = Import-Csv $path

$check = "ACCESS"
$new_value = "access"

$data | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.Column3 -match 'ACCESS'){
    if($_.Column5.Trim() -eq "") {
        $_.Column5 = $newvalue
    } elseif ($_.Column5 -match [\w,]) {
        $_.Column5 += "; $newvalue"
    }
}
}

$data | Export-Csv d:\Book11.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show some effort next time, ex. what have you tried. The keywords here is `Import-CSV`, `Export-CSV` and `Foreach-Object / %`.

```
#Sample csv
$data = @"
Column1,Column2
This function takes input.,
Other value,don't care
String as input,old_data
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

#To import a real csv-file, uncomment the lines below
#$path = "c:\mydata.csv"
#$data = Import-Csv $path

$oldvalue = "old_data"
$newvalue = "new_data"

$data | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.Column2.Trim() -eq "") {
        $_.Column2 = $newvalue
    } elseif ($_.Column2 -match [regex]::Escape($oldvalue)) {
        $_.Column2 += ", $newvalue"
    }
}

$data | Export-Csv $path -NoTypeInformation
```

Data after modification:

```
$data | ft -AutoSize

Column1                    Column2           
-------                    -------           
This function takes input. new_data          
Other value                don't care        
String as input            old_data, new_data
```

Your csv-file will look like:

```
PS C:\Users\Frode> $data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

"Column1","Column2"
"This function takes input.","new_data"
"Other value","don't care"
"String as input","old_data, new_data"
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. I just have one doubt. What is the purpose of'::Escape' in regex matching. I searched for it but couldn't find it.

Comment: Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At D:\BTP\manipulate.ps1:26 char:19
+ $data | Export-Csv <<<<  d:\Book11.csv -NoTypeInformation
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCo
   mmand

Comment: `-match` is a operator that tests if a string matches a regex-pattern. Since you want to match a specific text, we need to escape special characters like `. () \ [] {} + ?` etc. If it fails on `$data | export-csv` then your `$data` is empty, which means that probably never was imported in the first place. The sample works. Be sure to change the `$path` variable to your file and uncomment the line starting with `$path = ` and `$data = import`.